# Using Concatenate Function Inside The Image Function

Tags: google-sheets

I am using the concatenate function inside the =Image() function to build the URL in Google Spreadsheets.

=Image(Concatenate("""",Z2,""""))

Z2 has the URL stored in it

It does not returns the image and returns #Value!

Please help me fix this...

Answer (score 0):

If Z2 is a valid url (and thus already text) you should be able to just do:

```
=Image(Z2)
```